# How to remove package manually?

Tags: 12.04, apt

I customized a liveUSB of ubuntu, but one package (squid) did not install cleanly so I unsuccessfully tried to uninstall.  But everytime I boot up I get a crash warning with the message

```
sorry the package "squid3 3.1.16-1ubuntu1~ppa1~lucid1" failed to install or upgrade
```

What triggers this upgrade attempt and how can I just delete those files manually

Comment: Well nothing has worked so far...I still get that error, although I have removed the package via "apt-get purge squid3". There were still left behind files which I deleted manually (like /var/lib/dpkg/info/squid3-common.postinst which is now deleted) yet SOMEWHERE some script is hanging around which results in that error, and I cant find it.

Answer (score 3):

If the apt-get suggestions do not works, try this command:

```
sudo dpkg --purge --force-all squid3
```

From the [Man page for dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/dpkg.1.html):

> Force or refuse (no-force and refuse mean the same thing)
>                 to  do  some  things. things is a comma separated list of
>                 things specified below. --force-help displays  a  message
>                 describing  them.   Things  marked with (*) are forced by
>                 default.
>
> ```
>           Warning: These options are mostly intended to be used  by
>           experts  only.  Using  them  without  fully understanding
>           their effects may break your whole system.
>
>           all: Turns on (or off) all force options.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the package with

```
sudo apt-get purge squid3
```

The purge option removes the package **and** deletes any conf/upgrade files.  Use with caution.

Comment: Sounds like what I need. I'm thinking about your "use with caution" warning though, I can't really think of any harm that can come if it only removes files related to squid3, or am I not thinking though enough?

Comment: @user2323932 No, but if you point this at heavily configured DHCPd, Apache, Squid, or anything that took a lot of time to craft the conf files, that's what the warning's about.